# Filter list of scheduled tasks that contain specific string in Task To Run

Tags: cmd, scheduled-tasks

Actually I need to delete any task that contain some particular string.

I use `schtasks /query /v /fo list` to list all tasks and `schtasks /delete /tn XX /f`to remove a specific task.

Right now after I listed all tasks, I have to use Ctrl + F to find the string and copy paste manually.

Is it possible to show only task name that contain specific string in Task To Run? or even I can delete all the related task in one shot.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
Set TS = CreateObject("Schedule.Service")
TS.Connect("DESKTOP-UCDGI39")

Set rootFolder = TS.GetFolder("\")

Set tasks = rootFolder.GetTasks(0)

If tasks.Count = 0 Then 
    Wscript.Echo "No tasks are registered."
Else
    WScript.Echo "Number of tasks registered: " & tasks.Count

    For Each Task In Tasks
    A=Task.Name
    A = A & " " & Task.NextRunTime
    wscript.echo A
    Next
End If
```

For more info and sample code https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/taskschd/displaying-task-names-and-state--scripting-.

Comment: Looks like all you are getting.

Comment: Nop. It should be like Get-ScheduledTask -TaskPath * | Where{ $_.Actions.Execute -like '*Blabla.exe'}